# Is it possible to write two UPDATE functions with two conditions in a single query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

What I want to achieve is a ***single query*** to update those two values. *If possible.*

I have a table named ***employee*** , with 3 columns that are ***salary*** ,***city*** and ***employees***

I already completed what was needed to be done,

What I needed to do was :

- City 1 : update the current salary of +15% of the employees that make <800 a month.
- City 2 : update the current salary of +18% of the employees that make <800 a month.

| city | salary | employees |
| --- | --- | --- |
| city1 | 650 | employee1 |
| cit2 | 700 | employee2 |

my two separate query are:

#1

```
UPDATE employee
SET salary=  salary+ (salary* 15 / 100)
WHERE city= 'city1' AND salary<=800;
```

#2

```
UPDATE employee
SET salary=  salary+ (salary* 18 / 100)
WHERE city= 'city2' AND salary<=800;;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
UPDATE employee
    SET salary = salary * (1 + CASE WHEN city = 'city1' THEN 15 ELSE 18 END) / 100
    WHERE city IN ('city1', 'city2') AND salary <= 800;
```